# How do I disable add-ins in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

My Excel has started to crash on exit for multiple files. I ran the SFC check.

I wanted to disable add-ins but I don't seem to have that option.

I go to File, Options, Add-ins and I see a list of "Active Application Add-ins" but there aren't any checkboxes or buttons to disable add-in.

I guess I don't knew the keywords to search for as Google doesn't return anything useful for 2013 - all hits are earlier vintages.

How do I disable/inactivate add-ins in Office 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the "Add-ins" page in Excel options, there's a drop-down and button that looks something like this:

"Manage: `Excel Add-ins`[v] `[Go...]`"

The "Excel Add-ins" and "COM Add-ins" items will have checkboxes that allow you to disable items. The other categories should also provide ways to disable or remove them, if needed.

Comment: Excellent! Addressed OP and Office tools load much faster now - I really didn't need 4 different add-ins to make PDFs!!!!!